# How to save phpdom into xml?

Tags: php, xml, dom

I am using this simple php code to parse some information from html

```
 <?php 
/*** a new dom object ***/ 
$dom = new domDocument; 
$dom->loadHTMLFile('https://www.example.com/prehled.php'); 
/*** load the html into the object ***/ 
$dom->loadHTML($html); 

/*** discard white space ***/ 
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 

/*** the table by its tag name ***/ 
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table'); 

/*** get all rows from the table ***/ 
$rows = $tables->item(1)->getElementsByTagName('tr');  

/*** loop over the table rows ***/ 
foreach ($rows as $row) {
/*** get each column by tag name ***/ 
$cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td'); 


  echo 'lokalita: '.$cols->item(0)->nodeValue.'<br />'; 
  echo 'celkem: '.$cols->item(1)->nodeValue.'<br />'; 
  echo 'druh: '.$cols->item(2)->nodeValue.'<br />'; 
  echo 'novy: '.$cols->item(3)->nodeValue.'<br />'; 
  echo 'provoz: '.$cols->item(4)->nodeValue; 


}


?>
```

and here is the result: http://pocasi-dnes.cz/test-table.php.

Is there any way how to get simple xml output?
Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about *how to get simple xml output*, what do you want as the output  (give an example if possible)

Comment: can you include the xml output that you want ?

Comment: some xml output. I need just to start it working as a xml. The final one will be quite large, so i do not want to waste your time for creating all xml elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the DOM API to read the XML. The same API can be used to create and modify XML documents. Create a node using a `DOMDocument::create*()` method and append/insert it using `DOMNode` methods like `appendChild()` or `insertBefore()`.

In the following examples I optimized the reading using Xpath expressions.

```
$html = <<<'HTML'
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1. lokalita</td>
    <td>2. celkem</td>
  </tr>
</table>
HTML;

// the source HTML document
$source = new \DOMDocument();
// loadHTMLFile() for files / loadHTML() for strings
$source->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new \DOMXpath($source);

// the new target XML document
$target = new \DOMDocument();
// add a root element
$target->appendChild($target->createElement('data'));

// iterate the table rows in the source
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//table/tr') as $row) {
    // an element for the group
    $target->documentElement->appendChild(
        $locationNode = $target->createElement('umístění')
    );
    // first table cell
    $locationNode
      ->appendChild($target->createElement('lokalita'))
      ->appendChild($target->createTextNode($xpath->evaluate('string(td[1])', $row)));
    // second table cell
    $locationNode
      ->appendChild($target->createElement('celkem'))
      ->appendChild($target->createTextNode($xpath->evaluate('string(td[2])', $row)));
    // ...   
}

$target->formatOutput = TRUE;
echo $target->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
  <umístění> 
    <lokalita>1. lokalita</lokalita>
    <celkem>2. celkem</celkem> 
  </umístění> 
</data>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the xml output you want , but this will display your data as xml file

```
<?php 
/*** a new dom object ***/ 
$dom = new domDocument; 
$dom->loadHTMLFile('https://www.example.com/prehled.php'); 
/*** load the html into the object ***/ 
$dom->loadHTML($html); 

/*** discard white space ***/ 
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 

/*** the table by its tag name ***/ 
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table'); 

/*** get all rows from the table ***/ 
$rows = $tables->item(1)->getElementsByTagName('tr');  

/*** loop over the table rows ***/ 


header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><data>';

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo '<lokalita>'.$cols->item(0)->nodeValue.'</lokalita>'; 
    echo '<celkem>'.$cols->item(1)->nodeValue.'</celkem>'; 
    echo '<druh>'.$cols->item(2)->nodeValue.'</druh>'; 
    echo '<novy>'.$cols->item(3)->nodeValue.'</novy>'; 
    echo '<provoz>'.$cols->item(4)->nodeValue.'</provoz>'; 
}
echo '</data>';
```

you can replace "data" with anything you want.

Comment: Hello, thanks for help. it looks that it is what i need, but there is some error in https://snag.gy/jhlZry.jpg . have you any idea whats wrong?

Comment: Hello, try to remove all unnecessary line break on this code, and or put "header("Content-type: text/xml");" at the first line of this code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for helping me. I finally merge all information into one solution.